Avoid .sheet internal dismiss from dismissing parent
I am showing a sheet, but want the sheet to dismiss itself after 5 seconds elapse. I also allow the user to swipe away the sheet themselves. If a user swipes the sheet down just as the 5 seconds elapse, the swipe clears the object, but then the parent view dismisses itself -- am I doing something wrong here? (Xcode 15/iOS 16)
        .sheet(item: $message) { message in
            ZStack {
                Color.black.ignoresSafeArea(.container)
                Text(message.body)
                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .lineLimit(1)
            }
            .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.3)])
            .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
                    self.wonMessage = nil
                }
            }
        }


Please show a [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce the problem.

You can use the dismiss function inside the sheet to automatically dismiss it. In case the sheet is manually dismissed, the Dispatch block won't be executed and you won't face the bug.
struct AutoDismissableSheet: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var dismissAfter: Double = 5.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("I am a sheet!")
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + self.dismissAfter) {
                    self.dismiss()
                }
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Click me!") {
            self.showSheet = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet) {
            AutoDismissableSheet()
        }
    }
}

